# Winnovative HTML to PDF with CMYK Colorspace

Tags: cmyk, winnovative

I want to generate a PDF file for printing with the Winnovative HTML to PDF Converter. With `new Document(ColorSpace.CMYK)` I can declare the PDf to use CMYK.

But how do I define the CMYK color properly?

CSS doesn't seem to have a definition for CMYK-colors, only for RGB. CMYK will only come with CSS 5, it seems.

Is there any option to actually define those colors properly somehow? Or will the PDF still be defined based on RGB, just automatically converted in the background to CMYK?